# Adjusting Kendo MuliSelect Tag Width to fill the enitre input

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-multiselect

I have a Kendo MultiSelect with `MaxSelectedItems` set to 1, so user can select only one value. I'd like to make the `tag` to fill the input completely. Currently, it leaves some space after itself.

[image]

I'm aware of `TagMode`, but what I'm looking for is that the tag fills the entire input box.

This is what I'm using:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(x => x.field)
    .MaxSelectedItems(1)
    .Placeholder("")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .AutoBind(false)
    .DataSource(ds => ds
    .Read("SelectField", "API").ServerFiltering(true))
    .ItemTemplate("#:Code# - #: Text#")
    .TagTemplate("#:Code# - #: Text#")
    .TagMode(TagMode.Single)
    .HighlightFirst(true)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use CSS:

```
#select_id > li.k-button {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Just add some id to make this selector more specific

To maximize filled space you should also hide next `<input>`

```
#select_id ~ input {
    width: 0px !important;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Now, it adds horizontal space! And the caret blinks in the input, too! I'll be grateful for any more comprehensive solution. :)

Comment: Because there is `<input>` after `<ul>` in DOM structure and it has some width. You must also make it 0 width. EDITED

Comment: You can simply view what is the generated structure in your browser Developer Tools

Comment: It's IE 11. But the thing is that I cannot be sure about users... .

Comment: This selector is supported from IE 7, but there is a possibility that Telerik generate html in different way for MultiSelect. Try to find (on browser that not work) the html structure of input and your defined id

Comment: It's an Ajax content, and it seems IE's F12 isn't able to explore that. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Ok, I got it. It's the same `selector`, I just need to add `display: none` for the input selector.